# Get the grunt-php to work

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-php

I am trying to get the php server to work. 
I try to keep the code as simple as possible to make it work first. I have a folder in my D drive called `firethis` and it contains `index.php`. When i tell grunt-php to run, it gives me error. What am i doing wrong.

Thanks!

```
D:\>grunt php
Warning: Task "php" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

**config**

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        php: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    base: 'firethis'
                    }
                }
            },
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-php');
grunt.registerTask('default', 'php');
```

Comment: Are you loading the php task in the gruntfile? grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-php');

Comment: Yes i did and still nothing.

Comment: Do you have the grunt-php package installed in the firethis directory? npm install grunt-php?

Comment: 'firethis' is a folder, i have the package installed outside this folder (that is where i have all the packages.